# unable to make CORS request with Jquery

Tags: jquery, cors

I'm following this example:

```
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-cors-from-jquery
```

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON("http://172.28.101.197:3000/tests.json",function(config){

            var create_config_url = "https://act.domain.com/act2/act/createConfigfile?accountid=" + config.accountId + "&configfilename=" + config.name

            alert ("here goes nothing!");
            $.ajax({


                // The 'type' property sets the HTTP method.
                // A value of 'PUT' or 'DELETE' will trigger a preflight request.
                type: 'GET',

                // The URL to make the request to.
                url: create_config_url,

                // The 'contentType' property sets the 'Content-Type' header.
                // The JQuery default for this property is
                // 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', which does not trigger
                // a preflight. If you set this value to anything other than
                // application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain,
                // you will trigger a preflight request.
                contentType: 'text/plain',

                xhrFields: {
                // The 'xhrFields' property sets additional fields on the XMLHttpRequest.
                // This can be used to set the 'withCredentials' property.
                // Set the value to 'true' if you'd like to pass cookies to the server.
                // If this is enabled, your server must respond with the header
                // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'.
                    withCredentials: false
                },

                headers: {
                // Set any custom headers here.
                // If you set any non-simple headers, your server must include these
                // headers in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' response header.
                },

                success: function() {
                    alert( "I think I created a config" );
                // Here's where you handle a successful response.
                },

                error: function() {

                    alert ("That's an error!");
                // Here's where you handle an error response.
                // Note that if the error was due to a CORS issue,
                // this function will still fire, but there won't be any additional
                // information about the error.
                }
                //$.get(create_config_url,function(result){

            });

        });
});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://act.domain.com/act2/act/createConfigfile?accountid=AANA-EJ8SB&configfilename=rabdelaz.netstorage-pm.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: That's an issue with the server, not your jQuery.

Comment: damn. there's no way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: crossDomain: true

You can also try: contentType: "jsonp"

Comment: Where exactly? on it's own or nested inside something else?

Comment: Please be more specific. You could at a code snippet, for instance, which demonstrates what you mean (e.g. when using jsonp, simply using that content type is probably not enough).

Comment: do you even know what `crossDomain: true` is for?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it looks like that the server you are trying to communicate with doesn't have CORS enabled.If it has then your domain from where your sending the GET request is not in the server allowed domain white list. I don't see any issues with ajax.If you want to know more about CORS I recently have written a detailed post on CORS [here](http://aameer.github.io/articles/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors/). Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what is the back-end language you are using, but you need to use jsonp to make it more secure and cross-domain: true.
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in this case asterisk could be an allowed host
`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS` be sure your method is in the list.